# No simple subgroups in common implies order of groups relatively prime?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

Given two finite groups A,B.

If these two groups share no simple subgroups in common, can we conclude that the orders of these two groups are relatively prime?

Comment: In what sense  are you using the term "simple" here?

Comment: The only normal subgroups are the identity element and the group itself.

Comment: OK, yes,  I am familiar with that definition, so how are you using ``in common"?If $A$ and $B$ are completely different groups, they have no subgroups in common in the usual sense, but they need not have coprime order.

Comment: Sorry, I mean groups which are isomorphic.

Comment: But then, if you know Cauchy's Theorem, you know that two groups which both have order divisible by  a prime $p$ each have a subgroup of order $p$, and that is a simple group (and both subgroups of order $p$ are isomorphic). The answer of P. Vanchinathan therefore answers your question.

Comment: Indeed, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Groups of prime order are simple.

(2) If a prime $ p$ divides the order of a group, then it has a subgroup of
order $p$. (Cauchy's theorem)

Combining the above two answers your question positively.  Many times when people say simple group they mean non-abelian simple groups. In such a case take the cyclic group or order $n!$ and the symmetric group $S_n$  (with $n>4$) they have no common non-abelian simple group, however they have the same order.

Answer (score 0):

No : consider $\mathfrak{S}_3=\{Id,r_1,r_2,\tau_1,\tau_2,\tau_3\}.$ You have $o(\tau_1) =o(\tau_2)= 2$ whereas $<\tau_1>=\{Id,\tau_1\}$ and $<\tau_2>=\{Id,\tau_2\}$.